# Spring Boot Context Path Ignored With External Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have set the context path for tomcat as follows:

```
@Component
public class CustomContainer implements
        WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.setContextPath("/capripol");
        factory.setPort(8080);
    }
}
```

Navigating to localhost:8080/capripol works fine and I am prompted with my login screen, however after logging in my forms and controllers do not append to the context path, so instead of navigating to /capripol/MainMenu etc. they navigate to /MainMenu. How do I set the context path such that my form actions and controllers will be appended do it - why is the tomcat factory context path not setting?

Edit: My Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CapripolApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CapripolApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(CapripolApplication.class);
    }

    @Configuration
    public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/", "classpath:/images/")
                    .setCachePeriod(0);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ofcourse it won't work. That will only work for an embedded container, not for an external one. You cannot control your external container from within an application.If you want to change the context path you need to dive into your application server and configure it there.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to do it. You can add it to each controller, usefully if you want to change the context path

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo")
public class bar{
    @GetMapping(value = "/bar")
    public void stuff(){
        //doing stuff
    }
}
```

Or you can put it in your application.properties / yml

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/foo/*
```

There are technically some other more round about ways to do it, especially if you are using an older version of Spring, but I would think the application properties is what you are looking for.

Comment: this `server.servlet.contextPath=/foo/*` will not work with external tomcat. tomcat always take the war file name as the context path.